# Getting error message when opening deleted post on community

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-experience

When I am opening a deleted post using system admin User in community I am getting error.

Error Message :

> **The requested resource does not found.**

Same post when I am opening using Community User I am getting error:

> **Error Message: Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with
>   the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID:
>   653158745-159546 (1205476613)**

I want to show my custom message in both case.

Can I show my custom message here or not. If Yes then Using setting or Custom Code.

Comment: How will a User at the first place have access to a deleted post? Instead of allowing anyone to be able to access deleted post, the approach here should be not to display it.

Comment: It's a community and if anyone have that URL in bookmark or somewhere saved then this error will come in picture.